# UIAlertView delegate crashing the app

Tags: ios, xcode

I am setting the delegate to a UIAlertView in the following way:

```
PhotoViewController *controller = [[PhotoViewController alloc] init];

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                      initWithTitle: @"Announcement"
                      message: @"It turns out that you are playing Addicus!"
                      delegate: controller
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
```

Where PhotoViewController is not the current UIviewContorller. THe alert loads fine, but as soon as I press on the ok button, the app crashes and I get this error:

0x3a61a5b0:  ldr    r3, [r4, #8]  EXC BAD ACCESS

What does this mean?

EDIT:

```
+ (DejalActivityView *)activityViewForView:(UIView *)addToView withLabel:(NSString *)labelText width:(NSUInteger)aLabelWidth;
{
// Immediately remove any existing activity view:
if (dejalActivityView)
    [self removeView];

// Remember the new view (so this is a singleton):
dejalActivityView = [[self alloc] initForView:addToView withLabel:labelText width:aLabelWidth];

if ([labelText isEqualToString:@"Uploading photo (this process might take a while)"]) {
buttonCancel = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[buttonCancel addTarget:dejalActivityView
                 action:@selector(callCancelAlert:)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
buttonCancel.frame = CGRectMake(230, 540, 265, 40);
[addToView addSubview:buttonCancel];
[buttonCancel setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"socialize-navbar-bg.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[buttonCancel setTitle:@"Cancel upload" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

return dejalActivityView;
}

-(IBAction)callCancelAlert:(id)sender{

PhotoViewController *controller = [[PhotoViewController alloc] init];

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                      initWithTitle: @"Announcement"
                      message: @"It turns out that you are playing Addicus!"
                      delegate: controller
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
//[alert release];
}
```

Comment: Is this an exact copy of your code? If not, and `controller` is a `weak` property, then it may be set to nil before you can use it. In any case, check whether controller is non-nil in the debugger. All the best

Comment: Yes, this is the code. And this is the only reference I have to controller, as well as #import "PhotoViewController"

Comment: Hint: delegate is not retained by alertView;

Comment: @virtualnobi If it's `nil`, it ain't crashing. If it's non-`nil` and deallocated, it will.

Comment: In your PhotoViewController's .h file, did you set it to be a `<UIAlertViewDelegate>`?

Comment: @ H2CO3 - right, I completely mixed things up... too late.

Comment: I even thought of using instead of init, retain but I a in ARC

Comment: @GeneralMike - your right, I was missing the UIAlertViewDelegate but this didn't solve the problem. The app still crashes for the same error

Comment: Do you have any code in alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex: on PhotoViewController.m?

Comment: Please see the edit with the whole code

Comment: @GeneralMike no, I don't have any code yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delegates are not retained properties. This means that when `controller` goes out of scope, ARC will release it and, since it hasn't been retained by another object, it will be deallocated. When the alert view attempts to send a message to its delegate, the address is no longer valid and you get an exception.

The alert view's delegate will need to live longer than the alert view itself. Typically the object that creates an alert view should be the delegate. You should move the delegate code into the class that creates the alert view.